# Why my strings not equal?

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I have 2 Strings with name str1 that fills by data from url and str2 that fills by data from SQLite Database.str1 is "x4" and str2 is "x4" but when i want to compare them,they are not equals.

```
if(str1.equals(str2)) System.out.println(str1 + "=" + str2);
else System.out.println(str1 + "!=" + str2);
```

and always it prints `x4!=x4`.

I changed values but always is not equals.

Comment: Trailing spaces maybe?

Comment: Try printing `System.out.println(">"+str1 + "!=" + str2+"<");` to see better .

Comment: @Berger `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str1.toCharArray()) + "!=" + Arrays.toString(str2.toCharArray()));` would help you see a lot better.

Comment: no because i did str1 = "a" + str1 + "a" and str2 = "a" + str2 + "a" and they have no trailing spaces

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you  Andy Turner. it's works.

Comment: Could it be encoding issue? Try testing in if: new String(str1, UTF_8).equals(new String(str2, UTF_8))

Comment: @ArneHB It can't possibly be encoding and the constructor you suggest doesn't even exist.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Sorry you are right, it takes a byte array and not string as parameter so you'll have to do it like this: byte bStr1[] = str1.getBytes(ISO_8859_1); new String(bStr1, UTF_8); http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: @ArneHB OP already has two strings that `println` renders equally. Encoding has nothing to do with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing it to:

```
StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
string.append("'");
string.append(str1);
string.append("'");

if(!str1.equals(str2)){
    string.append("!");
}

string.append("'");
string.append(str2);
string.append("'");
System.out.println(string.toString());
```

It is most likely that there is a space, enter or a tab in one of the strings.
By adding a character at the start and end of each string then you can identify if that is the case.

If the problem persists then that probably means that one of the characters that is different is not printable. In that case try:

```
string.append(str1.toCharArray());
```

instead of

```
string.append(str1);
```

And do the same for `str2`.

Answer (score 2):

> Database.str1 is "x4" and str2 is "x4"

It might *look* like that, but I bet that's not the case. Why not print out the char array for each string, and that way you can identify what differs? I would suggest looking for leading/trailing spaces, non-printing characters, Unicode-related differences etc.

Answer (score 0):

It could have been caused either due to trailing spaces, as [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) said, or (maybe you didn't notice) due to case difference. Try this:

```
if(str1.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(str2.trim()))
    System.out.print(str1 + "=" + str2);
else
    System.out.print(str1 + "!=" + str2);
```

Use `trim()` to remove trailing spaces and use `equalsIgnoreCase()` instead of `equals()`, considering case difference.

Comment: I'm not sure that is what OP asked. He asked why they are not equal, not what he should do so that they pass the statement. But if I'm wrong then your is correct.

Comment: What if the difference isn't at the end of the strings? e.g. `Ab` and `A\0b` look the same in my console, but the `\0` won't be removed.

Comment: @AndyTurner In that case, wouldn't the strings just be "unequal"?

Comment: Indeed. But OP is asking why two strings which "look equal" aren't.